# Override WooCommerce templates via the theme issue

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm having difficulty overriding WooCommerce default shop template in WordPress.

I have a custom theme `my-theme` and in that theme there are files `woocommerce.php` which states that it is the

> The template for displaying all WooCommerce pages  *  * This is the
> template that displays all pages by default.  * Please note that this
> is the WordPress construct of pages  * and that other 'pages' on your
> WordPress site may use a  * different template.

I have also got a custom templates within `my-theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php`. This template includes the following comment -

> - The Template for displaying product archives, including the main
>   shop page which is a post type archive  *  * This template can be
>   overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.

It is this template that I want to override.  As I understand it, this *should* be the template that is used as the default shop page, but any time I edit it, the edits are not showing on the page.  My guess is that Woocommerce is using the default template and not this archive product template.  My question is how do I tell the Shop page to use this archive template.

Comment: Inside your theme (or your child theme) you add a folder "woocommerce". Insisde that "woocommerce" folder you add a copy of *archive-product.php* file. You must be sure [to declare WooCommerce theme support using the *add_theme_support* function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes) in order to get that working. Also be sure that the constant WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY is set to **false** if you have enabled WP_DEBUG.

Comment: I discovered the problem I was editing the `my-theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php` but I had also created a file `my-child-theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php` which was taking precedence.